# How to make two lines of best fit R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a plot with two sets of data. I was wondering if someone could help me print lines of best fit? Here is my current code. I am trying to use data I created that I'm calling gender_data:

```r
#Insert Data
library(readxl)
gender_data <- read_excel("Desktop/gender_data.xlsx")
View(gender_data)

#Matrix 
times_df <- data.frame(gender_data)
print(gender_data)

#Data Set
plot(x = gender_data$ "Olympic year", 
    y = gender_data$ "Men's winning time (s)", 
    xlab = "year", 
    ylab = "winning times", 
    ylim = c(7,13), 
    col = "green", 
    pch = "*")
points(x = gender_data$ "Olympic year", 
    y = gender_data$ "Women's winning time (s)", 
    col = "blue", pch = "`")
dput(head(gender_data))
```

My console is spitting out:

```r
#dput(head(gender_data))
structure(list(`Olympic year` = c(1900, 1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 
    1920), `Men's winning time (s)` = c(11, 11, 10.8, 10.8, NA, 10.8
    ), `Women's winning time (s)` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided the data you used and did not include what kind of model you would like to fit, here is example code using the `mtcars` data. The fit is done using a linear model `lm()`.

```
model_mpg_disp <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
model_mpg_disp_predictions <- predict(model_mpg_disp)  
plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$mpg)
lines(mtcars$disp , model_mpg_disp_predictions)
```

[image]

### EDIT

For an `ggplot()` way as asked by @hachiko, we can use `geom_smooth()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = mtcars,
       aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to use my own data set. I thought I called it "gender_data".  Have I not done this?

Comment: You should type this code.   dput(head(gender_data)) and then whatever appears in your console you should c+p into the question so we can reproduce

Comment: Ply do you also know a ggplot method ?

Comment: @SamLaski you have now, that is good! However, the plot that I would get is the following: https://i.imgur.com/tXgHjqr.png , I don't know what kind of fit you would have in mind. Fitting a line (perhaps a curve) can be done in many ways, so you will have to specify.

Comment: @hachiko Yes, I added a `ggplot` example in my answer.